# How to change the default values for directives in systemd?

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

How to change the system-wide default setting of a directives in systemd? For example the *DefaultDependencies* directive under *Unit* section by default has the value of `yes`, how to set it up the default to `no` for all units that don't specifically specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular change would break units shipped with systemd and other software.  It cannot be controlled by any option in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`.

If you are patching all the packages, you are free to also patch and rebuild systemd.

Comment: Ah, I thought "DefaultDependencies" only affects legacy SysV init scripts?

Comment: @SPArifSahariWibowo you were mistaken.